# StartActivityForResult not working in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, crop

I am trying to use Biokys [crop image library](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage) within my AsyncTask class and for some reason when trying to start the crop image class for a result, I get an error.

I have looked up what would be causing this and people have suggested that you should use:

```
YourClassName.this.startActivityForResult(Intent, RESULT_CODE);
```

But this isn't working for me.

If someone would be able to explain why this is happening, would be much appreciated.

Class:

```
    private void runCropImage() {


    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CropImage.class);

    // tell CropImage activity to look for image to crop 
    Bitmap filePath = bmImg;
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, filePath);

    // allow CropImage activity to rescale image
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);

    // if the aspect ratio is fixed to ratio 3/2
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 3);
    intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 2);

    // start activity CropImage with certain request code and listen
    // for result
    SetWallpaperAsync.this.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE);

}
```

Comment: are you calling it from async task??

Comment: in which method of AsyncTask you are calling it ? Is it `doInbackground ()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `SetWallpaperAsync.this` use `(Activity) context` like this:

```
    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE);
```

Comment: "The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type Context"

Comment: Oh that's right, see the edit. But I must mention that `Context` you are passing to `AsyncTask` should be an `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I can't accept just yet, have to wait 7 mins :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, CropImage.class);
```

with

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(YourClassName.this, CropImage.class);
```

?