# startActivityForResult is not recognized as function in AsyncTask

Tags: android, cordova, android-asynctask

I am making a phonegap project. I have made a native plugin in android for it. In it, AsyncTask is being called too. In it, I have `context.startActivity(intent)` function. I want to perform a task after this Activity completes. I found a solution to use `context.startActivityForResult(intent,i)` instead. But this function is not recognizable.

Then I tried,

```
((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

as per

[StartActivityForResult not working in AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656937/startactivityforresult-not-working-in-asynctask)

But at time of `startActivityForResult`,i got file installation error.

My code is as follows-

```
 public class MyPlugin extends CordovaPlugin
    {
        Context context;
        CallbackContext callback;
        @Override
        public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) 
        {
            super.initialize(cordova, webView);    
        }
        @Override
        public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException 
        {   
                context=this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                callback=callbackContext;

                if (action.equals("plugin1"))
                { 
                     System.out.println("Inside plugin1");
                     String myurl = args.getString(0);
                     if(haveNetworkConnection()==true)
                     {
                         System.out.println("Network connected");
                         new DownloadManager().execute(myurl);
                         return true;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         System.out.println("Network not connected");
                         callbackContext.error("Internet connection is not available.");
                         return false;
                     }
                }

                callbackContext.error("Some error has occured.Please try later.");
                return false;

        }

        public class DownloadManager extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
        {
            @Override
            public String doInBackground(String... arg0)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Knowing imei number
                    TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
                    String imei_device=mngr.getDeviceId();
                    //downloading and installing app
                    downloadapk(arg0[0]);
                    installapk();
                    PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "success");
                    result.setKeepCallback(true);
                    callback.success("Operation completed!!");
                    return null;
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    callback.error("Some problem occured.Try again later");
                    return null;
                }   
            }
         }
        public void installapk()
        {
             try
             { 
                Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+fileName)),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent,1);
             }
             catch (Exception e) 
             {
                Log.e("File installing Error", e.getMessage());
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                callback.error("Installation Failed.Please try later");
             }
         }
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

              if (requestCode == 1) //check if the request code is the one you've sent
              {
                     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
                     {
                        System.out.println("Result is OK");
                      }
                     else
                     {
                         System.out.println("Result is not OK");    
                      }
              }


            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        }
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Try to move installapk(); line in onPostExecute().

Comment: Hi ,Even if i do this,problem lies in the Intent that I am starting. I want to perform action after the Activitry is completed.

Comment: What is the Exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the error a `ClassCastException` ?

If so, it is because you are replacing the `Activity` (which is a `Context`) with the   application context, which is also a `Context` but not an `Activity`, and thus can not be casted to obtain the `startActivityForResult` method.

Does it work if you replace :

```
context = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

with :

```
context = this.cordova.getActivity();
```

?

[Here](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/) is an explanation about the different kinds of contexts, and when to use each.

Comment: Thankyou sir. It works now. :) I couldnot get hold of this minute mistake. But now,I am facing another problem.. onActivityResult() is not getting fired.

Comment: I don't know if and when the package manager sends a code back. It may be more robust to listen for ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED / ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED broadcasts : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED .

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class MyPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
    Context context;
    CallbackContext callback;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        context = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        callback = callbackContext;

        if (action.equals("plugin1")) {
            System.out.println("Inside plugin1");
            String myurl = args.getString(0);
            if (haveNetworkConnection() == true) {
                System.out.println("Network connected");
                new DownloadManager().execute(myurl);
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Network not connected");
                callbackContext.error("Internet connection is not available.");
                return false;
            }
        }

        callbackContext.error("Some error has occured.Please try later.");
        return false;

    }

    public class DownloadManager extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        public String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {
                //Knowing imei number
                TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                String imei_device = mngr.getDeviceId();
                //downloading and installing app
                downloadapk(arg0[0]);
                PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "success");
                result.setKeepCallback(true);
                callback.success("Operation completed!!");
                return null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                callback.error("Some problem occured.Try again later");
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            installapk();
        }
    }

    public void installapk() {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setDataAndType(
                    Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("File installing Error", e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            callback.error("Installation Failed.Please try later");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) //check if the request code is the one you've sent
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                System.out.println("Result is OK");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Result is not OK");
            }
        }


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,I tried doing this too. I am still getting the same error.